# Forest Admin Smart Action field multiline (Textarea)

Tags: forestadmin

Is there any solution to use an input value of type `Textarea` on Forest Admin Smart Action form ? I would like render a field like this :

[image]

Documentation said there is only `Boolean, Date, Dateonly, Enum, File, Number, String` types but use a multiline is a common use case, isn't it ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `widget` parameter when configuring your input fields on your Smart Action. Here is an example:

```
collection('customers', {
  actions: [{
    name: 'Charge credit card',
    fields: [{
      field: 'description',
      type: 'String',
      widget: 'text area', // <-- set the widget text area
      }],
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some documentation about this widget param ?
I need a dropdown field referencing a collection but I can't find information about this widget param

Comment: @CamCHN Yes, it is possible using the reference option. Let me share you some resources:

- [Similar question/answer](https://community.forestadmin.com/t/is-it-possible-to-show-list-of-all-possible-values-in-dropdown-when-using-smart-actions-form-field-with-reference/550/5)
- [Documentation](https://docs.forestadmin.com/documentation/reference-guide/actions/create-and-manage-smart-actions#handling-input-values)
- [Example](https://docs.forestadmin.com/woodshop/how-tos/create-a-custom-view#book-smart-action)

Comment: There is no documentation on this. You generally look at the .forestadmin-schema.json file and try to guess on how to override it's content. In your case, the answer is `widget: "belongsto dropdown"` with a `//@ts-ignore`, if you are using Typescript.